# wdCalendar buddle mousedown event

Tags: javascript, jquery, css

I have been banging my head for a few hours on this and am about to give up, so I figured I'd post my first question on SO.

I have implmented wdCalendar from http://www.web-delicious.com/jquery-plugins-demo/wdCalendar/sample.php and am expanding on their "buddle" floating div to fit my needs.  The issue is that when creating an event (via dragging the mouse on the calendar to expose the floating div for a quick add), all mouse events are ignored (via a jquery mousedown event returning false), thus when I add a select box to the "buddle", I cannot make any selections.  This can be easily tested on their demo page via just trying to highlight some text on the "buddle" div when it shows up.  Removing the mousedown function just assumes that the user clicked outside the buddle and removes the buddle.

The functionality works fine in FF 26.0 in Linux, but doesn't work in Chrome 31.0.1650.63 in Linux or IE.

The question is, how can I modify their mousedown event handler to account for clicks inside the buddle?

Thanks,
Ross.

Answer (score 1):

You can comment below code from jquery.calendar.js in plugin

```
if (e.pageX < 0 
    || e.pageY < 0 
    || e.pageX > document.documentElement.clientWidth
    || e.pageY >= document.documentElement.clientHeight) {

    dragEnd(e);
    return false;
}
```

Comment: This is too late to answer but might someone will get help